# Strange Bootstrap Container Breakpoint Behaviour

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

If I set the browser width to 1024px the following bootstrap container rule is being applied:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .container {
        width: 750px;
    }
}
```

If I extend the browser width to 1092px then the following bootstrap container rule is being applied:

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .container {
        width: 970px;
    }
}
```

There are no other CSS rules applied to the container, just the standard bootstrap rules:

```
.container {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
```

Can anyone explain to me why a browser width of 1024px isn't getting the `min-width: 992px` rules applied to it?

Comment: please recheck your question this is not matching If I extend the browser width to at least 1092 then the following bootstrap container rule is applied:

@media (min-width: 992px)
.container {
    width: 970px;
}

Answer (score 2):

I think you forget open close bracket `{` `}`

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
            .container {
                width: 750px;
                background: yellow;
            }
        }

        @media (min-width: 992px) {
            .container {
                width: 970px;
                background: red;
            }
        }
```